# Compare dataset with list and append the corresponding values

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I'm not really experienced with Mathematica and I cannot find a solution to my question. Hopefully, you can help me.

So I've got a Dataset

```
mainDataset = Dataset[{
       <|"noREG" -> 3, "maxR" -> 3, "maxP" -> 12|>,
       <|"noREG" -> 2, "maxR" -> 4, "maxP" -> 15|>,
       <|"noREG" -> 3, "maxR" -> 2, "maxP" -> 11|>,
       <|"noREG" -> 4, "maxR" -> 5, "maxP" -> 10|>,
       <|"noREG" -> 5, "maxR" -> 5, "maxP" -> 12|>,
       <|"noREG" -> 6, "maxR" -> 5, "maxP" -> 15|>}]
```

, which I want to compare with the list

```
 compareList = {{"noREG", "maxR", "range"}, {3, 2, {5, 9, 10}}, {4, 
    5, {7, 10, 12}}, {5, 5, {9, 11, 13}}, {2, 4, {7.5, 9, 10.5}}};
compareList // TableForm
```

in the following way:
If the value in noREG from mainDataset equals the value in "noREG" from compareList and the value in maxR from mainDataset equals the value "maxR" from compareList, then the mainDataset should be updated with a new column "range", which contains the corresponding "range" from compareList. I e. the final updated mainDataset should look like this:

```
mainDatasetUPDATE = Dataset[{
   <|"noREG" -> 3, "maxR" -> 3, "maxP" -> 12, "range" -> {}|>,
   <|"noREG" -> 2, "maxR" -> 4, "maxP" -> 15, 
    "range" -> {7.5, 9, 10.5}|>,
   <|"noREG" -> 3, "maxR" -> 2, "maxP" -> 11, 
    "range" -> {5, 9, 10}|>,
   <|"noREG" -> 4, "maxR" -> 5, "maxP" -> 10, 
    "range" -> {7, 10, 12}|>,
   <|"noREG" -> 5, "maxR" -> 5, "maxP" -> 12, 
    "range" -> {9, 11, 13}|>,
   <|"noREG" -> 6, "maxR" -> 5, "maxP" -> 15, "range" -> {}|>}]
```

Since my original mainDataset contains several million entries, I need a solution which is as little time consuming as possible. Many thanks in advance!

Cheers

---

Thanks you two for your solutions. But there's one problem. If I slightly change my mainDataset to mainDataset =

```
Dataset[{<|"noREG" -> 3, "maxR" -> 3, "maxP" -> 12|>, <|"noREG" -> 2,
     "maxR" -> 4, "maxP" -> 15|>, <|"noREG" -> 3, "maxR" -> 2, 
    "maxP" -> 11|>, <|"noREG" -> 4, "maxR" -> 5, "maxP" -> 10|>, <|
    "noREG" -> 5, "maxR" -> 5, "maxP" -> 12|>, <|"noREG" -> 5, 
    "maxR" -> 5, "maxP" -> 15|>}]
```

and the compareList to

```
compareList = {{"noREG", "maxR", "range"}, {3, 2, {5, 9, 10}}, {4, 
    2, {7, 10, 12}}, {5, 5, {9, 11, 13}}, {2, 4, {7.5, 9, 10.5}}};
```

it totally messes up both of your solutions?

Comment: Please don't use answers to make clarifications or additions; [edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/136746/edit) your question instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think this does what you are looking for.

I first made your compareList into an association:

```
    compareListAs = <|Thread[First[compareList] -> #]|> & /@ Rest[compareList]
```

Then I use the JoinAcross function with the "Outer" option and replacing the missing with an empty set.

```
    Dataset[JoinAcross[mainDataset // Normal, compareListAs, {Key["noREG"], Key["maxR"]}, "Outer"] /. Missing["Unmatched"] -> {}]
```

---

**Update**

Does changing "Outer" to "Left" give you what you are looking for?

```
Dataset[JoinAcross[mainDataset // Normal, compareListAs, {Key["noREG"], Key["maxR"]}, "Left"] /. Missing["Unmatched"] -> {}]
```

Comment: see my comment above

Comment: Is my update what you are looking for? It wasn't particularly clear what kind of join you were looking for.